# RxJS: How does shareReplay not store null values ？

Tags: javascript, rxjs

```
let btn = document.getElementById('btn')
let input = document.getElementById('input')

let input$ = defer(() => of(input.value)).pipe(
  tap(v => console.log('tap', v)),
  filter(v => v),
  shareReplay(1)
)
let click$ = fromEvent(btn, 'click').pipe(
  switchMap(_ => input$)
)
click$.subscribe(v => console.log(v))
```

I just want to store input$ when input value not null.
The problem now is that if the input value is null at first, it already store, filter not work.
[demoLink](https://codepen.io/molysama/pen/oKwoLj?editors=1111)

Comment: It's very unclear what you want to do.

Comment: Replay input$ only when input value not null.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, make a if-else before the input$

```
let btn = document.getElementById('btn')
let input = document.getElementById('input')
if (input != null){
  let inputValue = input
}

let input$ = defer(() => of(inputValue.value)).pipe(
  tap(v => console.log('tap', v)),
  filter(v => v),
  shareReplay(1)
)
let click$ = fromEvent(btn, 'click').pipe(
  switchMap(_ => input$)
)
click$.subscribe(v => console.log(v))
```